# Y_True in Loss Function not Correct

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I am building my loss function. However, when printing the value of the y_true tensor it is printing values with decimal points (i.e 0.25,0.569,0.958). This should not be true as the y_true should only have two classes 0 or 1. Here is my code:

```
@tf.function
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true= K.reshape(y_true, (K.shape(y_true)[0], -1))
    tf.print("tensors1:", y_true, output_stream=sys.stdout, summarize=50000)
```

Any reason why I am getting such an output instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: These decimal points are actually probabilities which ranges from 0 to 1. If you want either 0 or 1 then you have to assign probabilities less than a threshold (normally 0.5) to 0 and 1 otherwise yourself. But normally while calculating loss, you don't have to do this.

Comment: Yes I understand that should be the output of the y-pred but why for the y_true. Why it should give probability for the groundTruth (y_true)? Grountruth was already 0 or 1.

Comment: Did you check whether `y_true` was correctly labeled in the dataset?

Comment: Yes I did and it is 0 and 1

Comment: Now I think its a matter of debugging. May be you are updating `Y_true` value somewhere before the loss function gets called. Can you post your complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to detect the issue which is from my data generator. When I have rotation_range added it mess up the values of the pixels. This is because on rotation new pixels are created